# How do you register Zend Framework plugins in application.ini?

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

Currently plugins I write seem to work or not in random ways. Some do work, some don't, and some of them work part of the time, again with no obvious pattern. Even if all of the same are written and registered (apparently) in the same way. And I fail to find a proper documentation on where to put your plugins and how to register them in application.ini so I need to rely on examples I find in BLOGs or here. And chances are some of these examples assume things that may not be true in my code.

So I just give a simple example, and if you could suggest how to make it work, and give links to good articles on ZF plugins, I'd highly appreciate that...

Here's how I currently do things:

Directory structure:

```
/library
   /Zend
   /Plugins
       Myplugin.php
/applications
    /myApp
       /configs
          application.ini
       /modules
          /default
             /controllers
             /configs
             /views, etc
          /admin
             /controllers
             /configs
             /views, etc
       Bootstrap.php
/public_html
   index.php
```

Myplugin.php contains one class:

```
Class Plugins_Myplugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
     public function init()
     {
          print 'If I can see this, it's finally working!';
     }
}
```

application.ini relevant stuff looks like this:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
pluginpaths.plugins = "Plugins"
resources.myplugin =
resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = Plugins_Myplugin
;//I assume Plugins_Myplugin should be resolved into library/Plugins/Myplugin.php with    class Plugins_Myplugin inside, given present configuration. Most likely I am wrong somewhere
```

And the most common error usually is:

**Fatal error: Class 'Plugins_Myplugin' not found in /whatever/nevermind/domains/mydomain/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php on line 117**

Sometimes it *is* found if I "register" it with just *resources.myplugin =*, omitting whole *resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = Plugins_Myplugin* line.

So apparently this is not the right way to register your plugins. What is wrong with this way, and what would be the good way (using application.ini)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should know that your custom namespace is "Plugins" and 
consider adding these lines to your config :

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Plugins"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugins_Myplugin"
```

and make sure to delete these :

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../../library"
pluginpaths.plugins = "Plugins"
resources.myplugin =
resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = Plugins_Myplugin
```

Comment: Could you please explain what purpose those changes serve. I'm especially puzzled by suggestion to remove a good path too library in favor of a wrong one. Or suggestion to remove Bootstrap path, it would produce "No bootstrap path provided" error I believe.

Comment: okay i listed `bootstrap.path` , it shouldn't be removed , and regarding the lncludepath it was wrong and i had fix it for you

Comment: meanwhile I tested it and it seems adding namespace did the trick! Thanks a bunch! But include path was right and needed no fix. Sorry if my directory tree isn't clear enough but I hope you can see that library is two dirs above the actual application. Which resides in /applications/myApp, while library in /library

Comment: i would suggest: autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My", resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = My_Plugin_WhatEver , and put it the /plugins folder

Comment: Is there any way of passing constructor arguments to the plugin in application.ini? I keep getting complaints of "sub key already exists" if I attempt this:  resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin = 'My/Plugin' resources.frontController.plugins.myplugin.options.foo = 'bar'

Answer (score 0):

The method above wasn't working for me unless I changed:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Plugins"
```

to

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Plugins"
```

My directory structure is the Zend's default. My operating system is Windows 7 professional. I'm using WAMP...
Hope it helps as I can't (or don't know how to) comment on the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for u it's create some like this:

```
-applications
   +controllers
   +layouts
   +models
      -plugins
         **Myplugin.php**
   +views
```

In application.ini:

```
includePaths.plugins = APPLICATION_PATH "/plugins"
```

how i call this plugin....
Easy way, only need this:

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $Myplugin = new Myplugin();
}
```